# How do I add a custom launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I started by searching guides. I found [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) but neither of the main methods works anymore in 11.10.

1. The first solution, I have created the desktop file, however the file location given as `.gconf-> desktop-> unity-> launcher -> favourites`
   no longer exists. I can get to `/home/sayth/.gconf/desktop` but there is no longer a unity folder.
2. The second solution described right-clicking the desktop and creating a launcher. Right-clicking the desktop no longer produces a "create a launcher" option.

I manually installed geany 0.21 as the one in the repo's is outdated. It's installed and working correctly, and is executing from `/usr/local/bin/geany`.

How can I add it to the launcher?

Comment: Perhaps [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) you link to needs to be updated for 11.10.

Comment: refer to:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand

Comment: I would but dougs answer below was perfect.

Comment: > Disclaimer: This is my original work in the form of a youtube video. I have done a video on this topic.
[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncWUFEc3WXY](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncWUFEc3WXY)

Comment: Have a look at [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org): Xfce has very elegant support for this through the **menu editor**.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First thing I'd do is navigate to /usr/local/share/applications & see if there is a geany.desktop

If so then just drag onto the launcher.

**If not** then would just a minute or so  to set up. Your source has a 'geany.desktop.in', remove the .in & it's a perfectly good geany.desktop

**Edit**: the geany.desktop.in is a good template for your .desktop but needs some minor editing before copying or after. Lines 4,5,6 start with a _  that should be removed.

Ex. of edited geany.desktop (or edited geany.desktop.in

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Geany
GenericName=Integrated Development Environment
Comment=A fast and lightweight IDE using GTK2
Exec=geany %F
Icon=geany
Terminal=false
Categories=GTK;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-java;text/x-dsrc;text/x-pascal;text/x-perl;text/x-python;application/x-php;application/x-httpd-php3;application/x-httpd-php4;application/x-httpd-php5;application/xml;text/html;text/css;text/x-sql;text/x-diff;
StartupNotify=true
```

The source also has some geany icons in it, take the geany.png from geany-0.21/icons/48x48  & put somewhere like Pictures or Documents
Then copy the geany.desktop.in file sitting in the source folder to ~/.local/share/applications/geany.desktop

Ex. - if it was in Downloads/geany-0.21

```
cp Downloads/geany-0.21/geany.desktop.in  ~/.local/share/applications/geany.desktop
```

Then just go there,

```
nautilus ~/.local/share/applications
```

right click on geany .desktop > properties > click on the icon area & browse to your geany.png > open

Finally drag geany.desktop onto your launcher

Edit:
one advantage you'll see with a more 'proper' .desktop is it has a MimeTypes= line. Open up the .desktop in a text editor & take a look.

You can, if you want, now drag & drop any of those mimetypes on to the geany icon in your launcher & they'll open up in geany

Comment: I've put a bounty on the original question for 11.10 if you want to make a generic version of this over there so we have them all in one place.

Answer (score 27):

You can add a custom launcher in Ubuntu 11.10 by typing this in a Terminal

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

Once you have customized the item on your Desktop, drag it to the Launcher.

Comment: And because this command is complicated to remember, you can record it in an alias. Edit your ~/.bashrc `gedit ~/.bashrc` and add this line `alias cla='gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop'`  . I choose cla for Create Launcher App, I find it easy to remember.

Comment: It requires installing the gnome panel                                                sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~$ gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
The program 'gnome-desktop-item-edit' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel

Comment: @sayth: so after installation of gnome-panel, it works now right ?

Comment: I was debating whether to install it. Seems odd to need to install gnome-panel so the unity launcher works

Comment: Awesome !!! Too easy :) Just needed to install the gnome-panel package !!!

Comment: Works great under Ubuntu 15.04.  But, I am astonished why this isn't just built into the Ubuntu desktop simply by a right mouse context menu click.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/718643/340383 for a round-about way to workaround the problem where this is not easily and directly accessible from the right mouse context menu on the desktop.

Answer (score 11):

In Ubuntu 12.04 none of the above options worked for me when needing to create a launcher for a locally compiled app. This might be an app you created yourself or something you downloaded from source and then had to locally run make install.  I ended up needing a hybrid of tips found in this thread. Using Angry Birds as a hypothetical example, I did the following:

1. Create an angry-birds-launcher.desktop file and save it to the /usr/share/applications directory. You can do this in a single command with sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/xyz.desktop.  The actual file name is not important so long as it ends in .desktop
2. Gedit will open with a blank page. In gedit, input the following text:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Name=[Name of your app, for example Angry Birds. This can be free text.]
   Exec=[full path to your executable and executable name, for example /usr/local/bin/angry-birds]
   Icon=[full path to your executable's icon and icon name, for example /usr/local/share/icons/apps/angry-birds.png]
   Terminal=false
   StartupNotify=true
   ```
3. Double check for typos and save the file.
4. Open Nautilus and browse to /usr/share/applications and you should see in the list of apps your app with the correct icon.
5. Double click to launch the app.  A temporary icon will appear in the panel.  Because you launched an app from the 'official' directory (usr/share/applications), Ubuntu will finally display the menu option to lock the launcher into the panel.
6. Mouse over the launcher in the panel, right click and select Lock into Launcher. You should be all set at that point.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: great. it works on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 5):

I must have read this question dozen times, everytime I install Ubuntu on another computer :)

## **The easiest way to add a custom launcher is using a GUI tool.**

There are at least two I know of:

- **MenuLibre** - my new favourite :)
- **Alacarte** - the one I used for years, but now has bugs

---

### Installation

MenuLibre can be installed by running following command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install menulibre
```

or simply search the Software Center for `menulibre` and install from there.

Likewise, to install alacarte run:

```
sudo apt install alacarte
```

or search the Software Center for `alacarte`.

You only need one,so make a choice and you will be adding launchers in no time!

### Last but not least, here is a picture ( worth at least a thousand words )

[image]

Alacarte looks simmilar but is simpler and less advanced.

*Now about those [bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alacarte/+bug/1260846) I mentioned: Alacarte now has isues with PNG icons, so even though it makes you believe it is adding the icon they don't save and you launchers will be icon-less.*

Comment: This should probably have more votes.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Ubuntu 15.04, you can achieve this by starting your program and then right clicking on the icon in the dock and then selecting "Lock to Launcher".

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this tutorial: [" Howto create Application launcher and add icon to Unity in Ubuntu 13.04 / 12.10 / 12.04 "](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/create-application-launcher-add-icon-to-unity-ubuntu-12-10/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

### How to Add custom launcher without installing extra programs

I have verified this as working under Ubuntu 15.10. I do not know about earlier versions. The example below is for adding an Emacs desktop launcher to the desktop, and then changing the `Command` to execute my own script/program.

Open the Dash by pressing the [Windows Key](https://www.google.com/search?q=image%20windows%20key&client=ubuntu&hs=Wgv&channel=fs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC5ICGwprKAhUBGmMKHYRDCXMQ7AkIJw&biw=953&bih=518%20Windows%20key), which on my keyboard, is mapped to the `Super_L` key (reported by [xev](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) program). Once in the Dashboard, type the name of some program. In this example, I typed `emacs` because I want a launcher that launches Emacs, but instead runs a script I have that sets up some environment and then executes Emacs:

[image: Dash with Emacs]

Drag the icon to the desktop:

[image: Drag Emacs icon to desktop]

Right mouse click on the icon on the desktop, and then click on Properties (sorry, due to X windows grabbing, I cannot provide a screen-shot of that menu no matter what I tried!). This is what you might see before making modifications:

[image: Emacs launcher Properties before changing]

You can now change the `Command` to whatever you want. In my case I changed it to run-my-emacs.sh, which happens to be in my PATH, which I have previously set up in my startup scripts:

[image: Emacs launcher Properties after changing]

Click ESCape key to exit after making changes. Do note the bug in the screenshot above.

Double check that it works by double-clicking the icon on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a .desktop file for your launcher you may want to give a path to the application's icon there:

```
Icon=/full/path/to/icon
```

In case you just want to change an icon to other than default you can do so by opening the *Preferences* menu with a right click on the .desktop file. This will show the following dialog:

[image]

Click on the icon to open a file selector box to give a new icon path.

Local .desktop files can be found in `~/.local/share/applications/`, custom icons may be stored in `~/.icons/`.

**Only icons from .desktop files having executable permission will be shown.**

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 16.10, I just dragged an existing icon from the luncher panel to the desktop, edited it with a plain text editor and added it back, as suggested by bgoodr. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent answer (at least for uBuntu 18.04) is the one from J. Austin Rodriguez. From the bash terminal, type `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new` and use the `Create Launcher` GUI to define the shortcut.

The distinction between `Application` and `Location` in generated `.desktop` files should allow you to create shortcuts manually (by copying a template and editing the contents).

Application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=PATH-TO-APP-OR-COMMAND (eg. /usr/bin/atom)
Name=NAME (appears in Linux user interface eg. Files)
Comment=SOME-COMMENT (optional)
Icon=PATH-TO-ICON (eg. atom)
```

Location (or Link):

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
URL=PATH-TO-FILE
Name=NAME (appears in Linux user interface eg. Files)
Comment=SOME-COMMENT (optional)
Icon=PATH-TO-IMAGE (optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

A google-chrome app example, tested on Ubuntu 22.04

1. download a icon for the app, save at `/home/xxx/note.png`
2. create file: ~/.local/share/applications/chrome-youdao-note.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=youdao-note
Exec=google-chrome --app=http://note.youdao.com --new-window
Icon=/home/xxx/note.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

3. search `chrome` in launcher
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I resolved the issue by searching for my custom launcher in the action menu, and drag it to the launcher panel.

e.g. I wanted to create a custom launcher for Firefox, with direct choices for my different Firefox profiles.

- Stopped all instances of Firefox
- Removed existing Firefox launcher from launcher panel.
- Copied /snap/firefox/current/firefox.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
- Did my edits of ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
- Searched the Action menu for Firefox. Identified my custom launcher by the added menu items.
- Dragged the correct launcher to the launcher panel.

Tested on 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish