# Desktop launcher documentation?

Tags: .desktop, xdg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the syntax for .desktop files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37627/what-is-the-syntax-for-desktop-files)
>   [How do I add a custom launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher)

I prefer to create new desktop launchers (.desktop files) using just a text editor, for example to create an iotop launcher I write:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=iotop
Exec=gksudo "gnome-terminal -x iotop"
Type=Application
```

But I haven't found any documentation on the format. Can someone give me a link to the format specification?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The .desktop file specification is here:
http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/

An example .desktop file would be:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Foo Viewer
Comment=The best viewer for Foo objects available!
TryExec=fooview
Exec=fooview %F
Icon=fooview
MimeType=image/x-foo;
NotShowIn=KDE;
```

A .desktop file can have translations integrated, by specifying the language:

```
Name=Foo Viewer
Name[en_GB]=Foo Viewer
Name[el_GR]=Φου Βιούερ
```

If you want to add unity submenus to unity panel icon, then you can create a desktop file. An example from http://maketecheasier.com/8-really-useful-ubuntu-unity-quicklists/2011/05/07

First copy the original .desktop file and open it with your favourite text editor:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

Then edit the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Exec=firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;
StartupWMClass=Firefox
StartupNotify=true
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;Private;Safe;ProfileManager;MakeTechEasier

Name[en_US]=Firefox Web Browser

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=firefox -new-window
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Private Shortcut Group]
Name=Private Mode
Exec=firefox -private-toggle
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Safe Shortcut Group]
Name=Safe Mode
Exec=firefox -safe-mode
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[ProfileManager Shortcut Group]
Name=Start Profile Manager
Exec=firefox -ProfileManager
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Now run `nautilus ~/.local/share/applications/` and drag-and-drop your newly-created "Firefox" unity desktop file in the unity bar.

Answer (score 10):

The format of .desktop configuration files is a unified standard and described in the FreeDesktop.org [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).  The files specify how an application is launched, how it appears in menus, and so forth.

The GNOME Dev Center has a good [tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) on creating these files for your own applications.

Answer (score 7):

You can find information about .desktop file here: [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)

Comment: Please, be a little bit more verbose in your answers.

Comment: This is already mentioned in the accepted answer.