# How to create a ".desktop" file?

Tags: unity-dash, .desktop

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have downloaded several programs ([Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/), [Sublime Text Editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/), [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/)) and they all come in ZIP format. Once I uncompress them I can use them, but I cannot access them via the Dash Home Menu, like I explain in this thread:

- [How do I install 3rd party programs and make them appear in the Dash Home menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410053/how-do-i-install-3rd-party-programs-and-make-them-appear-in-the-dash-home-menu)

In that thread the answer was in creating a XXX.desktop file, populate it with random fields, and then move that file to a specific folder.

I now want to do the same for my Eclipe and SmartGit programs (as well as to any other programs I may end up using) so now I believe I need to learn how to create an XXX.desktop file with the correct fields and the correct instructions.

Where can I find the information to do that?

Comment: Are launchers considered ".desktop" files?

Comment: Yes, technically they are just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of `.desktop` files is described in the [Freedesktop Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).

Have a look at [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/) if you want a simple GUI to create and modify `.desktop` files.

Comment: Magnifier not found by Trusty's Dash though Manage Launcher (both variants) are. I've tried creating Magnifier.desktop both with 'Manage Launcher', 'Manage Launcher (Administrator)' & Arronax.

 root@JohnDesktop:/home/john# ls -l /usr/share/applications/Ma*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142 May  7 15:35 /usr/share/applications/Magnifier.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 322 Oct  1  2013 /usr/share/applications/Manage Launcher (Administrator).desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 281 Oct  1  2013 /usr/share/applications/Manage Launcher.desktop

Comment: I'm now using Arronax to create/modify .desktop files & my own app named Maintain Desktop Configuration Files (written in Gambas & calling the programs in the desktop-file-utils package)  to install a .desktop file from one of my home folders, then the Dash can find it. However, if I use a Terminal cp command then it cannot.