# How to restore home folder installed apps after reinstall Ubuntu(restore to App menu)

Tags: backup, appmenu

*I don't find answer here, there are similar answers, but its doesn't fit.*

I had reinstalled Ubuntu, I formatted only root, boot and had reinstalled. Home partition have been simply mounted without formatting.

**How to restore apps installed in home folder(somewhere there) after reinstall Ubuntu
(restore in Applicaton menu - cmd + a / win + a)? In order for me to be able to use them, add to favorites...**

Comment: You've tagged both xubuntu & lubuntu so what are you running?  What release?  How were those apps installed? (most *deb* packaged apps do not go into $HOME and a re-install without format will restore those anyway; though you were unspecific as to method or release, but formatting root likely prevent auto-restoration).  Details are needed as currently there are contradictions.

Comment: I'm not so good in Linux, I have Ubuntu, not L or X ubuntu,(I just not found Ubuntu tag...) I thought somebody from its users knows answer maybe. Some apps, like Intellij Idea, Telegram etc... were installed to home, and when I lunch reinstalled system some  apps were recognized by system and show up into the app menu and on the Dock(e g Intellij). But some apps not(e g Telegram). 
I want to understand why so, what does it depend on and how to recognize all possible for recognize apps

Comment: The starting point is what release you're asking about. Be it ubuntu, lubuntu or xubuntu (all on-topic here), the release details are a starting point and we currently don't know that.  If you're not using Lubuntu or Xubuntu, the tags should be removed.  You've also not provided details as to what packages, types of packages were installed?  How to depends on that information too.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS is my OS. I don't know how to answer question "You've also not provided details as to what packages, types of packages were installed?" At home folder I have Intellij Idea, Telegram Desktop, Joxi apps. Telegram not appeared in App menu, but I can run it by click to executable flle, and open Telegram I used in last system...

Comment: the types of packages mean did you grab a .deb for each of them, a .snap, .appimage, tarball (.tar.gz, .tar.bz), flatpak etc... Many programs are available in a choice of packages; it's the package choice you made that I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

For system wide installed apps, desktop launcher files are installed in a specific location, `/usr/share/applications` for applications installed using the APT package management system. Launcher files are small text files with the `.desktop` extension, that provide information to the desktop environment about the application (how to run it, what icon to use, etc.). These launchers are automatically read to build the application menu.

For installations you perform manually, i.e., applications you install under your home folder, you need to install such launcher files yourself under your local `.local/share/applications` folder. Launchers you put there will appear in the application menu for your user only.

Thus, find or create yourself [application launcher files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90345/desktop-launcher-documentation) and place them in that folder. These files may or may not have come with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH variable `echo $PATH` and make sure the location of the apps is listed in the output you get from the `echo $PATH` command if the location of the apps isn't listed in the PATH variable you'll need to add it in your bashrc `export PATH="/path/to/apps:$PATH"`