# What's snap folder in Ubuntu home? Is it apps themselves of only versions info?

Tags: snap

I found answers, but I have to clearly understand what to do with its. I had reinstalled Ubuntu, mounted home, and question appears [How to restore home folder installed apps after reinstall Ubuntu(restore to App menu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319904/how-to-restore-home-folder-installed-apps-after-reinstall-ubunturestore-to-app)

When I look files in home I found snap folders with my last apps names.
How I understood snap is a app versioning.
Is it only info about versions or or are these the applications themselves?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your other question, but the question itself is unclear. You've tagged three different OSes, and in the title mention a fourth (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu) so which are you using, which release?  What packages did you have installed? and of what type? At re-installation you have the option of having the system re-installing your package/applications at that point (not afterwards).  Usually only data is stored in $HOME or your home directory; not the programs themselves (they are re-installed via your installation choices or you start with a clean system)

Comment: My guess is you've only data in your $HOME directory from those apps, not the programs themselves.  I'm also guessing you opted to *clean* install your system (keeping only the user directory), thus have the installation not *attempt* to re-install the prior applications (which is nearly always my choice; it's far faster & easier to have the installer do it) giving you only the basic/clean system (re-using data files).   However your question really is unclear, and this is only guess.

Comment: Please elaborate the body of your question to make your question clear.

Comment: no..I added screenshot.  there aren't readme file etc... like in your suggested link

Comment: @virus_dmk Read the answer there again. The README is in `/snap`. In `/home/<user>/snap` is the configuration for various snaps.