# How to make a file executable as forwarder from a Desktop Subfolder?

Tags: .desktop, desktop-icons

in Ubuntu how to keep **executable a forwarder/ shortcut** from Desktop moved into a Sub-folder Desktop?
I use many softwares, and in my Desktop I have all the app forwarders/ shortcut, but some of them I collect in a Sub-Folder (always in the Desktop) but since I moved these Desktop forwarders to a Desktop Sub-folder called "Job", the forwarders are not anymore executable as forwarder, but are like any file to edit and not possible to execute. How to keep them "execution fuction" like as are in the Desktop?

**Edit 2** =
I made some test, and the first thing it's to open the sub menu into the sub-folder and allows the sub-folder to run the Icon Executable of the software as shortcut that were in the Desktop (to be run like are in the Desktop instead of to edit as generic file settled by default) but it seems it's not enough because the **Executable/ Shortcut** it's not showing the Icon of the Software but the Executable Generic Icon and if double click on it, it will not open the app.
With customized Executable need to be changed the two paramenters:

FROM

Exec=/home/username/ and so on

Icon= / and so on

TO add `cd..`, like that:

Exec=cd.. /home/username/ and so on

Icon=cd.. / and so on

But this around it works with the native Linux softwares, but not with the Wine softwares. And in both cases it doesn't show the Icon of each Softwares...
Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by a forwarder? Are you forwarding emails? How?

Comment: No, actually to run an app in Windows OS Environment, from Desktop, it calls "forwarder", but in Ubuntu/Linux I don't know if it's the most appropriate term about, but anyway i believe it's clear what I wrote.... How to keep executable an "Icon app Executable" from Desktop to a Sub-Folder Desktop and keep the Run Execution function as it is in Desktop. It doesn't matter from wine software to a native Linux software, but a simple thing like that how can be so complicated in Ubuntu? Example, in Zorin OS you just drug and drop the Executable and run the app like it is in the Desktop.

Comment: Oh you mean the [desktop launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90345/desktop-launcher-documentation)!

Comment: Yes, "desktop launcher" from a Sub-Folder in the Desktop.