# Adding a custom launcher to the Unity Launcher

Tags: 11.10, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Custom Launcher in 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/add-custom-launcher-in-11-10)

So I created a custom launcher using alacarte. Now how do I add it to the launch bar?

The code is just `LANGUAGE="ja" google-chrome`

I can keep the icon in the launch bar by right-clicking and checking 'keep in launcher' while Japanese chrome is running. But this icon opens chrome in English (the system language).

**Edit:** Not a duplicate. Launcher wasn't coded by hand, there's no .desktop to drag into the launch bar.

Answer (score 2):

The `exec` line needs to be:

```
env LANGUAGE="ja" google-chrome
```

So, open alarcarte and click on the 'Properties' option of Google Chrome.

[image]

Then, replace the existing command with the following:

`env LANGUAGE="ja" /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U`

[image]

After modifying it, pin it to your launcher and from now, Google Chrome would be in Japanese.

Comment: Didn't make any difference. Keep in mind that this was made using alacarte; not hand-scripted.

Comment: Yeah, but you'll still have a .desktop file somewhere. Take a look in `~/.local/share/applications`.