# Lock mono application to launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, keepass

I have mono application `.exe` (KeePass)

Also I have following script to launch it: (`keepass.sh`)

```
#!/bin/sh
mono `dirname $0`/KeePass.exe
```

Now I want to lock it in my launcher. But when I do it using (`right click` -> `lock to launcher`) and click to it nothing happen. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine(1st answer):

[How do I add a custom launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher)

Comment: I've tried it now, it create icon, but when I click it, another icon is created in the bar

Comment: tried with Exec =/path/to/sh and Exec = mono /path/to/exe

Comment: @RiaD, If you are getting the same results as me, the second icon created in the bar after launching the program is just the application actually running as opposed to the launcher you manually added. Once you close the application, you will only see the one launcher icon. I just live with there being two separate icons when it is running.