# How to launch apps installed from PPA?

Tags: command-line, unity-dash

I have installed a few apps from the Terminal by adding repositories and running commands but how do I access them? They aren't in the launcher and I can't see them in the Dash either.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

I ran the following lines of code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install geary
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom dash icon:

#### [How to create custom dash icons?](https://askubuntu.com/a/78747/92745)

In your case, you should use:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Geary
GenericName=Generic name you want
Comment=Your comments about this file
Exec=geary
Icon=geary
Terminal=false
Categories=Email;Geary;
MimeType=text/plain;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-java;text/x-dsrc;text/x-pascal;text/x-perl;text/x-python;application/x-php;application/x-httpd-php3;application/x-httpd-php4;application/x-httpd-php5;application/xml;text/html;text/css;text/x-sql;text/x-diff;
StartupNotify=true
```

If you want to launch it from the terminal, just type:

```bsh
geary &
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've hit [a known bug in Geary 0.2.1](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/5968).  For now you can launch Geary as follows:

1. Press Alt-F2
2. Type "geary" (all lower case, no quotes)
3. Press Enter

Keep in mind this is just a temporary workaround; the Geary 0.2.2 package should become available very soon as an update for you and make this unnecessary.

There's a couple of other points I'd like to address about your question:

- There's no need to add the Yorba PPA in this case, since it doesn't contain a Geary package for your version of Ubuntu.  In fact, the default Ubuntu 12.10 repository hosts Geary 0.2.x.  If you're interested you can [view the Yorba PPA contents here](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ppa).
- Terminal commands are generally referred to as "commands" rather than "lines of code."  I mention this because it may confuse people (especially us software developers!)