# Different Pictures For Items

Tags: 12.04, graphics, games

On my desktop I have alot of different shell files that run a game.  I want to replace those ugly shell file looks on your desktop and replace it with the game's logo.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may find an answer there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher

Answer (score 2):

Right click, properties. Then on the little picture that comes up in the window, click on it and pick the icon you want.