# How do I install Visual Studio Code?

Tags: software-installation, ide, microsoft, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded `VSCode-linux-x64` from [the Microsoft website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup). It's a 62 MB zip file. How can I install it on my Ubuntu system?

Comment: If you want to keep up with the filesystem structure: the best place to install this is in /opt/ If there is need for a binairy in /usr/ somewhere symlink the file.

Comment: Here: https://gist.github.com/brunolm/65a760f6130fd2e1d39c

Comment: Updated @BrunoLM gist with some changes in files names (can't put it as an answer because question is protected) https://gist.github.com/pomber/db44098f3413d5213aec

Comment: They are providing a .deb file now.

Comment: Direct PPA solution (since feb. 2017)  http://askubuntu.com/a/895790

Comment: Related: [How to install Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124276/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Note that Microsoft's binary packages are available only under a [proprietary license](https://code.visualstudio.com/license). This is unlike vscode's source code which is available [under MIT license](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/LICENSE.txt).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

## Update

VSCode is now [available as DEB file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download). You can download it and then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/path/to/code_1.XXX.deb
```

In case `dpkg` complains about missing dependencies, run:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

afterwards to fix the problem.

## Old answer

1. [Download Visual Studio Code for Linux](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=534108)
2. Extract it: `unzip VSCode-linux-x64.zip -d ~/path/to/VSCode`
3. Run the `code` executable to open Visual Studio Code
4. *(Optional)* Create a symbolic link to conveniently run `code` from the terminal:
   `sudo ln -s /path/to/VSCode/code /usr/local/bin/code`

Source (install instructions): https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: Also make sure that you are root while extracting files and then allow rwx permissions for the extracted files to desired user

Comment: One issue I am facing is how to add it launcher.  Because locking it launcher becomes useless once you close the VS Code. You have to open it from the sym link you created.

Comment: @mnstalemate see here on how to create a custom launcher http://askubuntu.com/a/78747/167115

Comment: One issue I had with installing VSCode was 7zip. If 7zip is installed, file-roller uses it. For some reason, 7zip throws errors when extracting the VSCode zip. So, the use of `unzip` rather than file-roller or another utility is vital.

Comment: How can I make files open by default with "Code" I couldn't find it in the list of programs to open the files with.

Comment: This worked for me: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux -> install the .deb package through Ubuntu software install

Comment: Indeed, [instruction have changed](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) →
“Install the package through a GUI package manager by double clicking on the package file, or through the command line:”

Comment: Note: If installing from the `.deb`, start from the command line with `code`.

Comment: sudo dpkg -i ~/path/to/code_1.XXX.deb

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, please take a little time to update it to include installation via apt as described in @zurfyx's answer bellow.

Comment: I receive the following warning when installing:
`gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/me/.gnupg'`

Answer (score 97):

Visual Studio Code enabled official Linux repositories on [February 2017 (v1.10)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
sudo apt -y install code
```

You can upgrade / dist-upgrade as usual

```
sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt -y dist-upgrade
```

Comment: This answer needs more up-votes and need be accepted by question owner.

Comment: Your code does not work for me. Please test it and consider following official instructions instead: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2973#issuecomment-280575841

Comment: See JeffRSon's answer for a more up-to-date method, similar to (but easier than) this

Comment: @terdon let me know if I'm mistaken, but IMO an answer shouldn't be a place to discuss another answer. Also,  I actually disagree with your second part, because this one doesn't require a .deb file beforehand (hence why I wrote it after the accepted Cactux's one).

Comment: You're quite right in that the comments of one answer are not the place to discuss another. But a single comment simply pointing out a perceived benefit of another answer isn't harmful and could be helpful. I sometimes leave one under my own answer if I feel that one of the others is better, for example.

Comment: (FAIL)   `E: Unable to locate package code`

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Hopefully it will work, I prefer to keep ability to update all my programs at once.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum JeffRSon's answer is not allowing to automate installation.

Comment: Unfortunately something is going wrong. On Ubuntu 18.04 following this results in several lines such as `W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3` after any `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 35):

Now there's a .deb package for Ubuntu and Debian besides the rpm/zip. It is available [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and may be installed as usual:

```
sudo dpkg -i vscode-amd64.deb
```

Works fine on Xenial. Maybe someone creates a PPA to simplify updates. Or it 'll become part of the official repository.

Update 03/17: Since version 1.10 (February 2017) there is [built-in support](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_official-signed-repositories-for-linux) for official Linux repositories. VS Code now can auto-update on Linux, although you have to install it one time manually.

Comment: this should probably be marked the correct answer as of 2016-06-05

Comment: @user25064 the answer that leveraged ubuntu-make worked totally fine for me 2016-10-11 however the .deb file certainly makes it easier as well.

Comment: Is there a PPA? Now there's a new release, it'd be so good to get it with apt

Comment: see Update - finally VSCode in Linux should be updatable easily

Answer (score 19):

Install the snap.

```
sudo apt install snapd-xdg-open
sudo snap install code --classic
```

Comment: Tried many of these answers with lots of fails.  This solution totally worked for me (Xubuntu VirtualBox).  What really makes this special is I can write this into a vagrant shell, and provision the virtual box up front.  Easy to then share the box with others on my development team.  This works great...

Comment: Please upvote this answer as much as possible as it is the latest best way. Other methods are outdated.

Comment: Now it should be `code`, not `vscode` (official one was released and `vscode` snap package is now abandoned). I am unable to edit due to changed character lower limit.

Comment: I succeeded in installing VSCode with just the second command  `sudo snap install code --classic` on Ubuntu 18.04.4

Answer (score 14):

Since they provide a `.deb` file now I recommend using that instead of the approach below.

The way I've done it is as follows. Using a terminal:

1. Create a directory for the files and change to this directory:

   ```
   mkdir msvs && cd msvs
   ```

The directory name is arbitrary.

2. Unpack the zip file in your new folder:

   ```
   unzip ../Downloads/VSCode-linux-x64.zip
   ```
3. Run the ide using

   ```
   ./VSCode-linux-x64/code &
   ```

You can also create a desktop link so that you can start it directly from the desktop or double-click in nautilus.

To create a menu entry:

4. At the terminal, create a file

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/MSVS.desktop
   ```

and copy and paste the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/opt/msvs/code
Name=MSVS
Icon=/opt/msvs/flurry_ios_visual_studio_2012_replacement_icon_by_flakshack-d5nnelp.png
Categories=Development
```

In my case the executable resides inside `/opt/msvs`.

```
sudo cp -R ~/Downloads/VSCode-linux-x64 /opt/msvs
```

I also downloaded an MS icon for this application from

```
wget http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/344/9/1/flurry_ios_visual_studio_2012_replacement_icon_by_flakshack-d5nnelp.png
```

and moved it to `/opt/msvs`:

```
sudo mv flurry*png /opt/msvs
```

Comment: Does simply double-clicking the executable (`Code`) not work to run it, from Nautilus? (At the moment I can only test this with Nemo and PCManFM.)

Comment: That works too.

Comment: This is actually what I was also looking for too. Thank you. BTW: the best icons to use is it's own: `Icon=/opt/msvs/resources/app/vso.png`.

Comment: The directory structure has now changed and the path to it's own icon is now: `Icon=/opt/msvs/resources/app/resources/linux/code.png`

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio Code doesn't have to be installed, per se. Instead you can unzip the archive wherever you want it, then run the program by double-clicking the file called `code` (which is the main executable).

Here's a GUI-oriented procedure for doing so:

1. Go to the [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) site and click [Download Code for Linux](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/D/5/0D57186C-834B-463A-AECB-BC55A8E466AE/VSCode-linux-x64.zip). (You should probably also review the [license terms](https://code.visualstudio.com/License) and [privacy policy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/dn948229).)
2. Make a new folder where you want Visual Studio Code to go. It's best to do this within your home folder (if other users want to use Visual Studio Code, it could be extracted separated for them--then any modifications or configuration changes will be per-user).

   This destination folder should be empty, as the `.zip` archive provided for download does *not* have everything in a top-level folder inside. For example, if you put software installed for your own user in `~/opt`, you could create a new folder inside there called `VSCode-linux-x64`.
3. Right click the downloaded .zip file and click *Extract To...*, then select the folder you created.

   If you prefer, or if your file browser doesn't show an *Extract To...* option, you could instead move the .zip file into the destination folder, right-click the icon, and click *Extract Here*.
4. To run Visual Studio Code, double-click on the `code` executable, which is one of the files that was extracted.

   Currently Visual Studio Code is "preview" software, which means it is still being developed and is not yet fully stable. Therefore you might prefer to launch it from a terminal so that you can see possibly useful errors and warnings. To do that, open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), `cd` to the directory where you extracted it, and run `./code`.

Comment: And what about updates?

Answer (score 2):

**Installing VS Code on Ubuntu**

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
```

This will download the gpg key and copy and make the apt files.
Then you can simply update and install *vs code*:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install code
```

- The advantage of this installation method is that you can simple update vscode using the *apt-get update* command. Works fine and I use *vs code* with the *vim plugin* for over 2 years (c, c++, python, md, latex, html, javascript ...).

**BTW, VS Code will be a standard package in Ubuntu 18.04 (end of april 2018)!**

Comment: Your advantage is actually not a real advantage anymore because the Visual Studio Code snap package (*vscode*) in Ubuntu is updated automatically too.

Comment: @karel I think advantage refers to "using the apt-get update command". Some of use *really just don't like snap packages* :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Install `gdebi` package installer
- Download `.deb` VSCode package from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
- Install downloaded package using `gdebi`

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the correct answer above (using PPA as of February), so I will add another detail here.

Visual Code depends on libgtk2.0-0 which it does not list as a dependency in the meta data. You might come across this problem if you, like me, setup minimal virtualbox installations just to troubleshoot difficult system level problems where you have to hack and slash packages which you don't want to do on your real host.

On minimal hosts, therefore the following is required in addition to what was mentioned above to get Visual Code to run:

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0
```

Answer (score 1):

From Visual Studio Code's official docs:

1. Download the .deb package from this [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).
2. Run the following command:
   `sudo dpkg -i ~/path-to-file.deb`
3. If you get dependency errors when using dpkg with a package, run:
   `sudo apt-get install -f`

**Note:** *Installing the .deb package will automatically install the apt repository and signing key to enable auto-updating using the regular system mechanism.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use new FLATPAK (flathub) repository to install on any linux distribution https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.visualstudio.code

FLATPAK automaticaly updates installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

- Download [the Powerbase installer script](http://www.thepowerbase.com/Vstudio/vscodeinstaller.sh) for Visual Studio Code
- Become root

  ```
  sudo -i
  ```
- Change to your download directory (probably `~/Downloads/`)

  ```
  cd /home/*yourusername*/Downloads/
  ```
- Run the installer script.  If there are no errors, it will just exit…

  ```
  sh ./vscodeinstaller.sh
  ```

That’s it. Nothing special about this one and it should work in any Linux distribution.  Just open your launcher and start typing Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Why `sudo -i`, it is enough to start `sudo ./vscodeinstaller.sh`. Better `sudo ~/Downloads/vscodeinstaller.sh`

Comment: Fail.  `http://www.thepowerbase.com/Vstudio/vscodeinstaller.sh` dead link.