# Microsoft Launches Visual Studio for Linux

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

Today, I read here that Microsoft Launches Visual Studio now support Linux.

http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/29/microsoft-shocks-the-world-with-visual-studio-code-a-free-code-editor-for-os-x-linux-and-windows/#.djfjf7:7EEX

but after downloading it here https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

I have a zip file but I dont know how to install it.

I need help on command to use.

Comment: See this topic: `http://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu`

Comment: Repost the question with the output of **uname –a** from terminal. It is essential one. Currently VS available only in 64 bit.

Comment: well, microsoft is the parent company of SUSE/Novell (openSUSE linux)

Comment: @mchid Are you quite sure? Novell and Microsoft are long-standing competitors; I believe a merger involving both of them would be well publicized in IT circles. Might you be thinking of the [Microsoft/Novell joint patent agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novell#Agreement_with_Microsoft)? My understanding is that Novell was bought by [The Attachmate Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Attachmate_Group)/Wizard Parent LLC which was bought by [Micro Focus International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Focus_International). But I haven't heard anything about Micro*soft* involvement.

Comment: @EliahKagan No, I'm not sure :) I believe what I heard was not accurate. Specifically, I remember reading the words "parent company" owned by microsoft speaking of the 2006 acquisition but I see now that was probably a bit of sarcasm poking at SUSE.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, choosing "extract here" may throw up an error and may not extract. You can, however, manually extract the archive.

Use this command to unzip the zip file to your user Home directory. Assuming the zip file is in your Downloads folder:

```
unzip ~/Downloads/VSCode-linux-x64.zip
```

If the zip file is in your Desktop folder and not Downloads, use these commands instead:

```
unzip ~/Desktop/VSCode-linux-x64.zip
```

---

To run, execute the following command:

```
~/VSCode-linux-x64/code &
```

It is also recommended you make a link so that you can easily run it in the future:

```
sudo ln -s ~/VSCode-linux-x64/code /usr/local/bin/vscode
```

Now, to run it in the future, you can execute:

```
vscode &
```

or press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type:

```
vscode
```

and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

---

Okay, it seems you have a 32 bit version of Ubuntu installed (i386) and the VSCode download is for a 64 bit architecture.

Here is how to install the 32 bit (i386) version.

Run the following commands:

```
wget "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=620885" -O vscode.zip
unzip vscode.zip
sudo ln -s ~/VSCode-linux-ia32/code /usr/local/bin/vscode
```

You should now be able to run Visual Studio by executing the following command:

```
vscode &
```

Comment: i got this oluwamayowa@Mayowa:~/VSCode$ ~/VSCode/Code
bash: /home/oluwamayowa/VSCode/Code: cannot execute binary file

Comment: @OlaitanMayowa are you using ubuntu 64 or i386 (32). Execute the command `uname -a` to find out. You need to be running a 64 bit capable version.

Comment: Linux Mayowa 3.2.0-72-generic-pae #107-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 6 14:44:10 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: @OlaitanMayowa this certainly appears to be an issue because you seem to have the 32bit otherwise known as the "i386" version of ubuntu. You can reinstall ubuntu using the "amd64" version instead. The "amd64" version is for all 64 bit systems including intel, you do not need amd to install this version, just a 64 bit capable processor.`  http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: @OlaitanMayowa Okay, I've provided some additional options  for a solution and have added these options to the answer for you.

Comment: @OlaitanMayowa 32 bit version is now available from Microsoft. I have edited the instructions.