# Error while installing Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, ide, zip, microsoft

I've been trying to install [MS Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) after it was announced today, on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer. I've read the official docs and setup [from Microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup) and I've read an answer to a [question on this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu) that asks for the installation process of Visual Studio Code.

But my question is specific, when I attempt to extract the downloaded zipped file to a new folder (as suggested by Microsoft), I get this error.

Even when I skip the extract to another folder process and directly double click on `Code`, I still get the same error.

**EDIT:**

Unzipped from command line. It looks like everything was unzipped, but then when I double click on `Code`, nothing happens at all.

If I try to run `Code` through the terminal instead, I get this, and nothing else happens -

```
5195:0430/005338:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! 
See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on. 
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment
```

[image]

Comment: That was my first thought. Downloaded thrice, with a computer restart after each failed attempt. Still no luck.

Comment: Unzipped through the terminal. I didn't get any errors, but the `code` doesn't give any response.

Comment: When I do `./Code` from the unzipped directory `vscode` (following instruction in Ron's answer here), I get this in the terminal, and nothing else happens: `[5195:0430/005338:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.`

Comment: If I click on Code in the "Files" application it starts for me. If I type "Code" or "Code &" in the terminal window, I get the error message that you got, but the program starts. You wrote "code" in your post, but for me it is "Code".

Comment: Setting +x flag and running `./Code` is OK for me, but I had to extract from the terminal with `unzip VSCode-linux-x64.zip` (in an empty folder). Also downloading the archive gives 408 for me at the end (near 99%).

Comment: @guntbert thanks for the info! I'm aware of that, which is why I had posted the final status of my problem as an edit to the question. As for the comments here and below the answer, those were mainly just responses to the posters. The problem which still persists is the same as the part I've mentioned in my edit, along with the exact error message.

Comment: @Manish may I suggest that you clean up those comments that are no longer relevant?

Comment: as i can't post answer , it seems to me that you try to install it on 32bit version of ubuntu , so please check this topic

http://www.zahraaonline.com/3433

Answer (score 5):

`cd` to the directory where you have downloaded `VSCode-linux-x64.zip` and run `unzip VSCode-linux-x64.zip -d ./vscode` to extract the contents of downloaded .zip file to a folder `vscode`. I did it and it did not give me any error. I could not run it by clicking `Code` because I am getting `-bash: ./Code: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`, mostly because I am using 32-bit linux.

**EDIT**: Since you said you are getting `default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment` error, try installing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` by `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. It might help.

Comment: I was able to unzip it through the terminal, but when I click on "Code", nothing happens. My computer is 64-bit, so that's not an issue I guess.

Comment: This is what I get when I do `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` : `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version.
ttf-mscorefonts-installer set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.`

No effect on Visual Studio Code. It just doesn't launch, no matter if I try it from the terminal or from the folder.

Comment: i tried all this , but what really worked for me is this topic http://www.zahraaonline.com/3433