# How Do I Setup Microsoft Visual Studio: Code as a Default Editor?

Tags: command-line, microsoft

Microsoft Visual Studio Code is a really nice editor and I would like to make it my default normal (not terminal) text-editor over Gedit, Emacs, or Vim. (I know, I'm so evil.)

There's no way for me to add it via a GUI option and I've looked at several online suggestions, but all of them are fairly out of date or unhelpful.

Do any of you have any suggestions? I'll take a terminal solution, but if you guys have a GUI one, that'll do too.

Comment: Did you installing visual studio via wine ?

Comment: @FirstStrike Visual Studio Code is a different, cross-platform thing (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu). Ryan: How did you install it?

Comment: Definitely native, not Wine. It's actually a pretty nifty editor, give it a try.

As for installation, I basically just copied and pasted it into a folder. I launch the program's main executable from that folder.

Comment: Does Visual studio code exist on `/usr/share/applications` ?

Comment: The answer depend on **how did you install it ?**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Microsoft Visual Studio Code's Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_setting-vs-code-as-the-default-text-editor):

> ### Setting VS Code as the default text editor
>
> #### xdg-open
>
> You can set the default text editor for text files (`text/plain`) that
> is used by `xdg-open` with the following command:
>
> ```
> bash xdg-mime default code.desktop text/plain
> ```
>
> #### Debian alternatives system
>
> Debian-based distributions allow setting a default **editor** using
> the [Debian alternatives
> system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives), without concern
> for the MIME type. You can set this by running the following and
> selecting code:
>
> ```
> bash sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/code
> ```
>
> If Visual Studio Code doesn't show up as an alternative to `editor`,
> you need to register it:
>
> ```
> bash sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor $(which code) 10
> ```

Additionally, there is [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/703) mentioning following:

> Some need you to set the default for a mime type like:
> `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`
>
> ```
> [Default Applications]
> text/plain=code-insiders.desktop
> ```
>
> Which adds Open With Visual Studio Code - Insiders (Ctrl+O) to the
> nautilus context menu.

Comment: This solution worked for me - thanks! (Actually with VScode snap package on Manjaro distro)

Answer (score 6):

These two worked for me:

1. Using xdg-utils:

```
xdg-mime default code.desktop text/plain
```

2. In this file:

```
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

replace this line:

```
text/plain=gedit.desktop
```

with:

```
text/plain=code.desktop
```

Note: update-alternatives affects **non-graphical environment (terminal) only**

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04 works with text/plain=code.desktop inside /usr/share/applications/defaults.list  Thanks!