# Can't run VSCode from a terminal

Tags: command-line

Recently, I have installed `Visual Studio Code` on my Ubuntu 15.10 and I have a problem running it from a terminal. I did everything correctly what they had written on official site of VSCode, but when I type `code .` it gives me output `command not found` .

Comment: Provide more Informations about what you've done , share the link from the official site of VSCode ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I have taken a look at this, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: No command 'code' found, did you mean:
 Command 'cde' from package 'cde' (universe)
 Command 'node' from package 'node' (universe)
 Command 'node' from package 'nodejs-legacy' (universe)
 Command 'tcode' from package 'emboss' (universe)
 Command 'cobe' from package 'python-cobe' (universe)
 Command 'cdde' from package 'cdde' (universe)
 Command 'cone' from package 'cone' (universe)
 Command 'ode' from package 'plotutils' (universe)
code: command not found

Comment: this is output when I try to run Code from terminal

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup#_linux these are steps on official site that I went throuhg

Comment: Be aware of upper- and lowercase. Please run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/code` and append the output to your question by editing it. Don't put it in a comment. Makes a mess. .

Comment: You obviously didn't do everything correctly. Please list the exact commands you used to install VS Code.

Comment: Please add the extra information through edits to your question and not comments, this will make it easier for others to see your question and help you

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29958039/5531761)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run VS Code from the terminal, create the following link substituting `/path/to/vscode/Code` with the absolute path to the Code executable by running this command

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/code
```

Comment: I have done it but still it doesn't work .

Comment: What's the output of the above command so I can improve my answer ?

Comment: This worked for me. I had installed my vscode on Ubuntu 18.04 through the Ubuntu Software app. My installation path was /usr/bin/code

Answer (score 1):

How do you install vscode (tar.gz or .deb)
personnaly i install with .deb
download .deb file (for example code_1.5.3-1474533365_amd64.deb), and then :

`sudo dpkg -i code_1.5.3-1474533365_amd64.deb`

that's all.
it's tha simple way to install it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using **visual studio code insiders**, use `code-insiders` command

Answer (score 0):

As of 9/29/2016 and latest version of Code. In VS Code, open the "Command Palette" (View -> Command Palette) then type "Shell Command: Install 'code' in command PATH.

See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac I'm guessing it will be similar on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is not an option when I type 'shell' into the command palette

Comment: This does not appear to be an option on Ubuntu. That shell command is not in the palette.