# How to download and install Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ide

I am totally new to Linux and programming. I want to learn Python with the Visual Studio Code text editor, but I'm having trouble to download and install it.

I downloaded VSC from the official website, but I received an error message from the package installer when I tried to install it: Wrong architecture 'amd64'.

The second method I tried was running this command in a terminal: `sudo dpkg -i vscode-amd64.deb` (I saw it on a YouTube video), but I received this error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive vscode-amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vscode-amd64.deb
```

Can someone please help me? My Linux version is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @muru. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much @cl-netbox for editing my post to make it more readable. You made me learn valuable lessons. I will definitely focus on makining future posts more readable.

Comment: @I.Wewib I would rather you start with this post

Comment: @muru I've done it.

Comment: No problem @muru. I need to thank you for helping me post good questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have downloaded the wrong packages and as you didn't provide further details about the architecture of the Ubuntu system you use, here are the correct download links ->

- For 64-bit Ubuntu editions : [code_1.9.0-1486023356_amd64.deb](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb)
- For 32-bit Ubuntu editions : [code_1.9.0-1486024310_i386.deb](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux32_deb)

Open a terminal in the directory where you have saved the downloaded file (or change to it).

On 64-bit Ubuntu editions execute this command :

```
sudo dpkg -i code_1.9.0-1486023356_amd64.deb  
sudo apt-get install -f
```

On 32-bit Ubuntu editions execute this command :

```
sudo dpkg -i code_1.9.0-1486024310_i386.deb  
sudo apt-get install -f
```

More information -> [Running VS Code on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

Note : The direct download links and the file names are valid as of writing this answer today.
They will change with every new release, hence check the [Download Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) site.
This additional information is just meant to be for other users reading this post in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It solved my problem. I indeed have a 32-bit Ubuntu edition.

I also want to thank you for editing my post to make it more readable. This made me learn valuable lessons, which I will keep in mind for future posts.

Comment: Can I bother you with one more thing @cl-netbox? Do you perhaps know why I'm not getting any syntax highlighting and how I can fix it? Here is a screenshot of VSC: http://imgur.com/a/nzFOj

Comment: I know what the problem was. I didn't get syntax highlighting because the file I was opening was a text document. When I gave it the extension ".py", I did get the syntax highlighting. How stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the 32-bit version to match your computer. It can be found at https://code.visualstudio.com/#linux32-downloads-stable

Comment: You are right heynnema. My Ubuntu is indeed 32-bit. Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate it. I do have to give the vote to @cl-netbox though since his/her answer was more helpful.