# how to install visual studio?

Tags: software-installation, visual-studio-code

```
sudo dpkg -i code_1.20.0-1518023506_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for wolfubuntu: 
(Reading database ... 189470 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack code_1.20.0-1518023506_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.20.0-1518023506) over (1.20.0-1518023506) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of code:
 code depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package code (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 code
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install ./code_1.20.0-1518023506_amd64.deb` which resolves the dependencies automatically. See https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/250300 for details.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-do-i-install-visual-studio-code/616363?s=1|0.0000#616363