# How add extensions to Visual Studio Code through command line?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, software-installation, ide, visual-studio-code

It is possible to compile Visual Studio Code and install it through terminal as explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run-from-source) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-do-i-install-visual-studio-code). Now I wonder, does anyone know how is it possible to install/add extensions to Visual Studio Code through Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the command line help with

```
code -h
```

(A **man** pages doesn't exist.)

```
Extensions Management:
  --extensions-dir <dir>                                         Set the root path for extensions.
  --list-extensions                                              List the installed extensions.
  --show-versions                                                Show versions of installed extensions, when
                                                                 using --list-extension.
  --install-extension (<extension-id> | <extension-vsix-path>)   Installs an extension.
  --uninstall-extension (<extension-id> | <extension-vsix-path>) Uninstalls an extension.
  --enable-proposed-api <extension-id>                           Enables proposed API features for an extension.
```

Hence all you need is the extension-id or extension-vsix-path and then

```
code --install-extension (<extension-id> | <extension-vsix-path>)
```

E.g. the **ms-python** package can be installed  by

```
code --install-extension ms-python.python
```

Comment: And [`--force --install-extension`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58434#issuecomment-421023851) to update.