# VS Code internal error

Tags: snap, visual-studio-code

I'm getting a bizarre error seemingly out of the blue. A google search came back empty. I'm stumped here. Running Ubuntu 18.04:

```
code . 

internal error, please report: running "vscode" failed: cannot find current revision for snap vscode: readlink /snap/vscode/current: permission denied
```

'sudo code .' will result in the same error message.

Comment: Maybe try `sudo code .` Not sure as I don't use product but it might work. Don't open and save any files though if it works. Just exit Visual Code and restart normally with `code .`. I presume your snaps aren't being updated automatically by `systemd` boot and it's trying to do it at run-time instead.

Comment: Another point to make is it's an **internal error** and you should report it to MicroSoft.

Comment: I'd rather do a reinstall, just to be sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Visual Studio Code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-do-i-install-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Not a duplicate as the installation of VS code does not address the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /snap/vscode/
```

Did the trick.

Comment: Setting 777 permissions for this folder is a bad idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why?

Comment: [Is setting CHMOD to 777 Dangerous?](https://superuser.com/questions/1326775/is-setting-chmod-to-777-dangerous)