# Open folder in vscode - path bar is not showing correctly

Tags: 18.10

I have recently upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10 and when I try and open a new folder in vscode, the open folder window doesn't show the path as it should.

[image: image with the window vscode open file dialog]

It still lets me click on the folder names, and it will navigate to them, but it doesn't dispaly the '/' between them. The contents in the window don't seem to be aligned either, the Size and Modified attributes are pushed to the right.

vscode was installed from the snap store.

Comment: that's the way it is on my own vscode and do remember this is gnome not unity!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Visual Studio Code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-do-i-install-visual-studio-code)

Comment: vscode is working just fine(I have installed it trough snap). The problem I have encountered appeared when I updated Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10, and it appears when I try and change the folder inside the editor.