# How to install Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, snap, visual-studio-code

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and I need to install [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) in my machine i tried:

```
sudo snap install --classic vscode
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you add more detail about why it didn't work?

Comment: I think you were following [one of the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/917087/816190) which was written in 2017. However in 2019, Microsoft released an official snap package due to which the older one was abandoned. This was already included in one of the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-do-i-install-visual-studio-code/917087#comment1927470_917087). I have updated the package name in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install Visual Studio Code Ubuntu 18.04, ust press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
sudo apt install code
```

[Source](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

Comment: Better way now is from the DEB that adds the correct apt-key per version .. see https://askubuntu.com/a/616082/165511

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mitch's answer:

If you are not best friends with your shell (yet), you can also just visit [Visual Studio Code home page](https://code.visualstudio.com) and click on their [download link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb).

When downloaded, you can double-click the .deb file which will open the Ubuntu Software Center and let you install vscode using a graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

After `18.04` version, [the following one-line terminal code](https://snapcraft.io/install/code/ubuntu) works well.

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```