# Install VSCode on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, snap, 19.04, visual-studio-code

I'm having difficulty installing VSCode on Ubuntu 19.04 and most of the instructions I find are for installing VSCode on Ubuntu 18.04/16.04.

First, I tried installing VSCode from Ubuntu Software.  When I open vscode after this, the program shows up blank.  This continued even when I restarted the computer and then installed and reinstalled VSCode.

Next, I tried to install VSCode using [the `.deb` option from the VSCode website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download).  I got the same problem where when I open VSCode, all I see is a blank window.

Finally, I tried to install VSCode using snap, [following these instructions](https://snapcraft.io/vscode).  Again, VSCode is blank when I open it.

I next tried to install using `apt`.  I ran `snap remove vscode` and was told it's not there, after which I ran "sudo apt install vscode" which told me that vscode is already the newest version.  I think this happened because I only uninstalled the version that I had installed with snap.

I poked through [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_vs-code-is-blank) and saw that sometimes problems with GPU acceleration can cause VSCode to appear blank.  I tried to disable the GPU acceleration by running `code --disable-gpu`, but when I re-opened VSCode it was blank again.

**TLDR**: How can I install VSCode on Ubuntu 19.04?  My next plan is to attempt installing the `edge` or `test` builds.

I already read [this question about installing on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124276/how-to-install-vscode-in-ubuntu) and followed the instructions.  I wasn't able to install VSCode following those directions.

**UPDATE**: Here is the output from `/var/log/apt/term.log` which shows my `vs code` installation attempts.

```bsh
Log started: 2019-05-16  14:05:45
Selecting previously unselected package code.
(Reading database ... 176942 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../code_1.33.1-1554971066_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.33.1-1554971066) ...
Setting up code (1.33.1-1554971066) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Log ended: 2019-05-16  14:05:48

Log started: 2019-05-20  12:13:37
(Reading database ... 186403 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing code (1.33.1-1554971066) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Log ended: 2019-05-20  12:13:37

Log started: 2019-05-20  12:13:54
Selecting previously unselected package code.
(Reading database ... 184660 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../code_1.34.0-1557957934_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.34.0-1557957934) ...
Setting up code (1.34.0-1557957934) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Log ended: 2019-05-20  12:13:57

Log started: 2019-05-20  12:35:47
(Reading database ... 186403 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing code (1.34.0-1557957934) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Log ended: 2019-05-20  12:35:47

Log started: 2019-05-20  12:38:15
Selecting previously unselected package code.
(Reading database ... 184660 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../code_1.34.0-1557957934_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.34.0-1557957934) ...
Setting up code (1.34.0-1557957934) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Log ended: 2019-05-20  12:38:18

Log started: 2019-05-20  12:49:21
(Reading database ... 186403 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing code (1.34.0-1557957934) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Log ended: 2019-05-20  12:49:21

Log started: 2019-05-20  21:37:40
(Reading database ... 186403 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing code (1.34.0-1557957934) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Log ended: 2019-05-20  21:37:40
```

**Another Update**: I resolved the issue.  I repeated all of my previous steps for uninstalling VSCode, and I also checked `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`  This directory contained some config files for VSCode, which I removed.  I also checked the `.config` directory in my home directory and it also contained some vscode configuration, which I removed.  After doing this full scrub of VSCode-related files, I downloaded the `.deb` file from the VSCode website and installed it using Ubuntu's Software installer.  Success!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete section of /var/log/apt/term.log showing the vscode install.

Comment: Try launching code from terminal, see if you're shown any errors/messages. The snap version should work without any problem. First try uninstalling vscode running `sudo apt purge`, then clear the files it left behind by running `sudo rm -rf .vscode/` in your home directory. Then install vscode again by running  `sudo snap install code --classic` (don't use the software center)

Comment: @SirajusSalekin I followed all the steps you suggested.  Now when I open vscode from the GUI, it still shows up as blank.  When I try running it from the command line, `code .`, I get this error: `bash: /usr/bin/code: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

try this commands in your terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
sudo apt install code
```

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I have already resolved the issue, as I noted at the end of my post.