# Creating a link to an application that is installed but does not show up in Applications folder

Tags: shortcuts

[image]New to Linux and Ubuntu.

I want to create a link to **Slic3r** in a folder i've created on the desktop. All the other apps that I wanted to show up in this folder I copied from the **/usr/share/applications** folder and they all worked.  Slic3r does not seem to show up in that the applications folder though.  I installed in using a long complex list of instructions that I can't find now.  It works perfectly, but I still would like to create an icon in the design folder that I've created on the desk top. Where else might I be able to find the app if it does not show up in the applications folder?

Comment: It depends on how you installed it and where you placed the executable. Is it in /opt? In /usr/? In a subfolder of your home? Without knowing exactly where you placed it, it is impossibile to help you. If you run it through a terminal, you can use `which` to know where the executable is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a custom launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher)

Comment: if you do not know the location of the application, type `which slic3r` or the name of the binary.

Comment: Hi Charlie, the question is where you left it.  Slic3r can be simply downloaded and run locally as it seems, which will you give you no output on the suggested command above. How do you run it? Command or double click on the icon? If the latter, where is the icon?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I guess there is no shortcut (icon) and he wants to create one. Otherwise he would've copied it to the desktop like he did before. Since he can execute it he either knows where the executable is located or it is in `$PATH`, then `which` will work.

Comment: @danzel sure, that's why I am curious where he left it. By icon, I mean the executable. I downloaded it; if I double click the executable in`/bin` it runs fine! I am a bit surprised by OP' s previous questions :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 10):

In Ubuntu, shortcuts to applications are text files with *.desktop* file extention. These are usually provided with the application if you installed it via the Software Center or *apt*. However, if you installed it using a different method, you most likely have to create the *.desktop* file yourself.

First of all, you have to know the location of the executable you want to run. If you don't, but can start it by typing its name in the terminal, the command `which` will tell you its absolute path (e.g.`which firefox`).

Now open your favorite text editor (e.g. gedit). A simple *.desktop* file may look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=<application_name>
Exec=/path/to/executable
```

Replace the name of the application and the path to the executable. Save the file as * *.desktop* (e.g. *slic3r.desktop*) to your Desktop.

If you want it to appear in the [Dash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-dash-intro.html), place a copy in

- `/usr/share/applications` (visible for every user)
- `~/.local/share/applications` (visible for your user only)

---

**Additional Notes:**

- If the executable is in the `$PATH` variable (i.e., you can run it by typing its name in the terminal), you don't have to provide the absolute path in the *.desktop* file. However, I'd recommend using the absolute path.
- There are also applications that provide a GUI for creating starters, for example [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/) and [MenuLibre](https://launchpad.net/menulibre)

Comment: Making a standard, basic `.desktop` file is *extremely* easy, and takes only four lines!

Comment: I agree with Jacob. It's unnecessary to have an external app take up hard drive space just to make a .desktop file. I typically just keep a template. If one was so inclined, one could even write a script that does the same function, but it's more of a nuisance

Comment: Now that I thought about it, I agree with you, it's really easy. Although I still use Arronax because I make a .desktop file once a year and don't want to look up the syntax everytime. I don't understand why this functionality was removed from Ubuntu, especially because you can still edit name, command, description, comment and image of an existing .desktop file. Just like the removal of "New empty document" from nautilus... stupid design flaws disguised as "features"...

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the slic3r folder showing it's location.  None of these files seem to be an executable.  I did mark slic3r.pl as excecutable in properties but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: No, when I type slic3r at the terminal prompt it does not run.  at present, the only way I can run it is from the ubuntu button (is that what is referred to as the 'dash'?),   I did lock it to the luancher, but I would rather that it were in my "design" folder with all the other apps that I use for design and printing.

Comment: So there obviously is a .desktop file already. If it's not in `/usr/share/applications`  it should be in `/home/<username>/.local/share/applications`. Note that files and folders beginning with a dot are hidden by default. You can unhide them by pressing [Ctrl]+[H] in nautilus.

Comment: Ok, yes...I found it in ~/.local/share/applications named slic3r_pl.desktop.  Can I just copy this to the folder I am trying to get it to run from?