# Create desktop shortcuts for media streams

Tags: 18.04, gnome, vlc, lts, streaming

Challenge: Creating 7 different shortcuts for audio streams like this one:

http://live-icy.gss.dr.dk/A/A03H.mp3.m3u

A few years back when I searched for a way to do this in windows it took me a bout 8 minutes to google and set up in VLC using this method:

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=48172

I'm now three hours into Google and I haven't found a way to do it on Ubuntu Gnome. Slightly desperate here.

Tried creating a shortcut for vlc by both dragging the app with alt down (create link), but that didn't give me permission to launch. Root is probably owner, I'm guessing. Even though I created the shortcut as a user.

Then I tried this:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Skrivebord
```

(/Desktop but in Danish)

This created the shortcut to VLC, but I can't edit the url that I need to stream automatically once launced (and seriously, why do I need to know code to create a shortcut?? Oh well, never mind that for now).

I only need the final step - starting the web stream. How do I put in the url - if possible - in each shortcut so that the stream starts automatically?

And one last thing - it honestly doesn't need to be vlc. That was just what worked on Windows, but if there's another lightweight audio player more suited, I'm all ears.

Cheers, and thanks in advance!

Comment: May I please ask if you are using the GNOME desktop? It's the default for Ubuntu, but sometimes folks change things. Please click [edit] and confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something basic missing here, [`.m3u`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) format itself is a list of shortcuts/URL's. No need going in such long way.

- Right click on that link and save as copy of `A03H.mp3.m3u` file.

  If the streaming URL doesn't have known extension. Copy its URL, paste it in a text file and save it with `.m3u` file extension.

Just click on it, and it will start straightaway playing with default player.

If you want more control like play with different player than default, Use launchers (`.desktop` files)

- It is a text file, here format info: [How do I add a custom launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/78730/26246)
- Change important line similar to: `Exec=<player> <streaming-URL>`

  For default player: `Exec=xdg-open <streaming-URL>`

**References:**

- [Wikipedia: M3U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U)
- [How do I add a custom launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/78730/26246)
- [`man xdg-open`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdg-open.1.html)

Comment: God damn, man... Yes... Yes, that worked. How am I that thick?

Thanks a lot!

Now if I really wanted the links to open in a specific program other that what I set default for m3u, I'd have the same problem. But no need to cross the river to get water ;)

Comment: My problem actually stands, I think. Another station has this link: http://stream.taleradio.dk/web128 - and saving that just starts a stream download.

Comment: @LasseKristoffersen , :) no problem updated my answer to cover that and added generic solution other than media cases.

Comment: That is honestly brilliant! I had no idea that was possible. It worked like a charm, thanks a lot! I've upvoted your answer, but I don't have the reputation for the vote to show.

Comment: @LasseKristoffersen You welcome, you need to reach 15 to be able to vote. But you can set it as the "Accepted" answer, there is a button to the left near vote ones for that.