# how to upgrade nextcloud client on ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade, snap, nextcloud, appimage

I have upgraded from ubuntu 16 LTS to 18 to 20 recently. Works nicely.
My version is
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Now my nextcloud client lets me know it needs an update with a pop-up. When I follow the pop-up it downloads an appimage form this link
https://download.nextcloud.com/desktop/releases/Linux/Nextcloud-2.6.5-x86_64.AppImage

All good and fine, but after the download that file sits in my download folder. How do I get it "installed" so it becomes the new version?

My ps lists this:

```
$ ps waux | egrep next
hanscees    2414  0.1  2.0 1718460 157308 ?      SLl  14:48   0:02 /usr/bin/nextcloud
```

Should I move the appimage to that binary or something, and why doesnt it update automagically?

Comment: How did you install the nextcloud client to begin with?

Comment: probably by apt, since it shows a lot of installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

Make the appimage file as executable file and run it.

```
chmod +x name_of_the_appimage_file
```

Comment: I know howto run an appimage. But I want it to start automatically everytime my system boots. I am looking for the way ubuntu runs appimages. I can write a script myself, but that is not the point. I want to know the proper way ubuntu 20.x runs appimages.

Answer (score 0):

So after searching longer, I found out the best way to update the nextcloud agent, at least if you also want integration in ubuntu 20.x. You shouldnt use an appimage at all.
You can of course, but better integration is possible using apt.

You are supposed to use an apt-get PPA like is described here:
[https://launchpad.net/~nextcloud-devs/+archive/ubuntu/client](https://launchpad.net/%7Enextcloud-devs/+archive/ubuntu/client)

Probably, after the upgrade to ubuntu 20.x this PPA needs to be added (again).

I thought I needed the appimage because the old version of the nextcloud version shows a pop-up saying you should download an appimage.

And probably also my conclusion is ubuntu has no proper way to run appimages as a service, as I wanted to, since the client should run after every boot.

Answer (score -1):

[What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it)

here the answer your question maybe mark as duplicate since the link shows how to install appimage , you can save lot of time if you google stuff than ask a whole question and wait for answer

also here step
change permission of app image to executable
**chmod +x < appname >** 
**./< appname >**

edit:
You want to run from anywhere you can simply write bash script or copy your appimage choose which one is suitable for you
here sample script

#!/bin/sh
/Path/to/appimage/appimage

and save this file as any name you want to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin dir
Change permission to allow this to execute by
chmod +x /usr/bin/script-name 
You need sudo permission to execute command

after you can execute any where you want 
also check following

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix \ 
 
[How do I add a custom launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher) 

there one more trick you can direcly link appimage 
**ln < app image> /usr/bin/**

Comment: that is not an answer to my question. I want to know howto install it. Installing should mean it runs again after a reboot of course. Is there no ubuntu way to install appimages?